# JpaRepository make a query to select all element that contains the array of tags

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

I have a postgres db table named "challenge" which contains a 'tags' text column in that each tags of the challenge is stored as "tag1,tag2,tag3...".

So I need to make a request that can check if a challenge contains all tags in the provided array but I don't know how to make this.

My repository method:

```java
@Query(?)
Page<Challenge> findByTags(String[] tags, Pageable pageable);
```

What i've done so far it's a query which works with one tag but not with an array:

```sql
SELECT * FROM challenge WHERE tags LIKE '%' || :tag || '%';
```

Comment: Are the tags always in the same order in that database table, or might we see one row where the tag colum is "tag1,tag2,tag3" and another where it is "tag2,tag3,tag1"?

Comment: They are not in the same order, this was an example. I can't predict the number of tags and not even which ones it will be...

Comment: Then you might need JPA Criteria Queries for that, build and chain some predicates that each compares with one of the tags in the array: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries